SQL Cursor multiply two sets of lines
I am using Hana data studio (SQL) and need to write a cursor that takes the original dataset, makes column age set to 0 and sets the the fiscal quarter to the iterated value over a distinct list of fiscal quarters in the input data set (FY24Q1, FY24Q2, FY24Q3) and unions it to the original dataset for every distinct fiscal quarter.
Input sample data set:



Name
Age
Fiscal_Quarter




James
22
FY24Q1


Henry
32
FY24Q2


Ethan
45
FY24Q1


Jake
19
FY24Q3



Output:



Name
Age
Fiscal_Quarter




James
22
FY24Q1


Henry
32
FY24Q2


Ethan
45
FY24Q1


Jake
19
FY24Q3


James
0
FY24Q1


Henry
0
FY24Q1


Ethan
0
FY24Q1


Jake
0
FY24Q1


James
0
FY24Q2


Henry
0
FY24Q2


Ethan
0
FY24Q2


Jake
0
FY24Q2


James
0
FY24Q3


Henry
0
FY24Q3


Ethan
0
FY24Q3


Jake
0
FY24Q3




I would say dont use a cursor, look into looping.

Why do you think you need a cursor? You want to avoid loops for this type of thing. But what I don't understand here is the output.

Why even a loop? Just join a tally table?

I rolled your changes back, we do not want images, text tables are best

Why is there only 3 quarters in 24?

@SeanLange No data for quarter four yet. The real question is how they already have data for quarter 3.

Maybe to be clear, this is a simple example of what I am trying to accomplish. I don't know if a cursor is the right way, however the purpose behind the output is for data scaffolding and data visualization purposes.

@JoelCoehoorn Ah the FY is based on the input data. Maybe this is so strange because the question has been abstracted to post. The Age column is also very bizarre.

No a cursor or any kind of looping is absolutely not the way to go here.

This is a truly bizarre requirement but definitely don't need any loops here. There are multiple ways this could be solved, here is one of them.
First I need to create a table to work with. This could be your existing table.
create table #Something
(
    Name varchar(10)
    , Age int
    , Fiscal_Quarter varchar(10)
)
insert #Something
values
('James', 22, 'FY24Q1')
, ('Henry', 32, 'FY24Q2')
, ('Ethan', 45, 'FY24Q1')
, ('Jake', 19, 'FY24Q3');

Now that there is a table to work with we just a query to get the existing data and then a cross join of Names and Quarters.
Something like this should work. It produces the desired output in your question from your sample data.
select Name
    , Age
    , Fiscal_Quarter
from #Something

union all

select Name
    , 0
    , Fiscal_Quarter
from
(
    select distinct Name from #Something
) n
cross join
(
    select distinct Fiscal_Quarter from #Something
) q

